# Writing on sector 0?

Tags: assembly, bootloader, hard-drive, sector

I need to do a bootloader in asm, and i need to write my aseembly code in sector 0 of a usb flash device. Is there is any program that enables you to do this, without manually using interrupts? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "without manually using interrupts"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try RawWrite which is a tool for Windows. http://www.chrysocome.net/rawwrite

If you are using Linux, you could try adapting some of the commands on this page
...http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-copy-mbr/